# Recursively modify list with irregular shape

Tags: python, list

The `aa` list is my input, and the `bb` list my desired output. The operation is rather simple (change every element in `aa` to string appending some characters, while keeping the original shape), but the way I do it seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Is there a better (more Pythonic) way to do this?

```
aa = [0, 5, 6, [8], 3, [9, 2]]

bb = []
for e1 in aa:
    if type(e1) == list:
        bb2 = []
        for e2 in e1:
            bb2.append('sss' + str(e2))
        bb.append(bb2)
    else:
        bb.append('sss' + str(e1))

print(bb)
['sss0', 'sss5', 'sss6', ['sss8'], 'sss3', ['sss9', 'sss2']]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive list comprehension to achieve this

```
def f(data):
    return [f(i) if isinstance(i, list) else 'sss{}'.format(i) for i in data]
```

For example

```
>>> aa = [0, 5, 6, [8], 3, [9, 2]]
>>> f(aa)
['sss0', 'sss5', 'sss6', ['sss8'], 'sss3', ['sss9', 'sss2']]
```

Comment: Selecting this one for conciseness. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do what your question title is already hinting at, i.e. use recursion:

```
def transform(ll):
  if isinstance(ll, list):
    return list(map(transform, ll))
  else:
    return 'sss%s' % ll

print(transform([0, 5, 6, [8], 3, [9, 2]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to do this recursively that is a little more concise is

```
def addSSS(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        # map takes a function, and a list and returns a 
        # new list that is the result of applying the function 
        # to each element. list() converts the result to a list
        return list(map(addSSS, item))

    # if it's not a list simply append the string and return that value
    return "sss" + str(item)

bb = list(map(addSSS, aa))
```

Maps are nice because they don't evaluate each element right away, only on demand, of course here it gets evaluated right away when you call `list()` to turn it back to a list

This has the additional advantage that it works when your list nests deeper like `aa = [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2]]]`